# When is $D_n\approx\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, dihedral-groups

We define the group $D_n$ to be the dihedral group of order $2n$ (equivalent to the group of rotations and reflections on a regular $n$-gon) and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ to be the group of automorphisms of a group. Additionally, we say that $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

My conjecture is this: $D_n\approx\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$ if and only if $\varphi(n)=2$. In other words, this is a property only held by the groups $D_3$, $D_4$, and $D_6$. Is this true?

Here is my reasoning. As we know, $D_n=\langle r,s\ |\ r^n=s^2=e, rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$. As for the elements of the automorphism group, we can define two variables, $\rho^i: s\mapsto sr^i$ and $\sigma^j: r\mapsto r^{f(j)}$ for some valid value $j$ and function $f(j)$. Looking at this geometrically, we can think of $\rho^i$ as rotating the line of reflection for $s$ by an incriment of $\frac{i\pi}{n}$, and we can think of $\sigma^j$ as mapping the incriment of rotation from $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ to $\frac{2f(j)\pi}{n}$. However, we need to be careful how we choose $f(j)$. By definition, because $\sigma^j\in\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$, $\sigma^j$ must be a homomorphism $\sigma^j: D_n\rightarrow D_n$.

As an example of a poorly chosen and invalid $f(j)$, let's say that $f(j)=j$. Now, consider the group $D_6$. Here, we have $\sigma^2: D_6\rightarrow D_6$ such that $r\mapsto r^2$. Let's look at what this does to the set of rotations in $D_6$:

$$1\mapsto1;\ r\mapsto r^2;\ r^2\mapsto r^4;\ r^3\mapsto1;\ r^4\mapsto r^2;\ r^5\mapsto r^4$$

Clearly, this is not an automorphism, as an automorphism is by definition surjective.

In fact, this is a problem we run into whenever we have a mapping $\sigma^j: r\mapsto r^{f(j)}$ and $\gcd(f(j),n)\neq1$. In other words, $\sigma^j$ is *only* a valid mapping if $f(j)$ and $n$ are coprime. As anyone who has taken an elementary number theory course can tell you, there is a function that tells you how many numbers are coprime to $n$ and what those numbers are, defined exactly as $\varphi(n)$. Therefore, $\sigma^j$ will be an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$  of order $\varphi(n)$ defined as $\sigma^j: r\mapsto r^{f(j)}$ where $f(j)$ is the $(j\mod n)$-th element in the set of numbers coprime to $n$ arranged from least to greatest.

All this is to say that $\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)=\langle\rho,\sigma\ |\ \rho^n=\sigma^{\varphi(n)}=e, \rho\sigma=\sigma\rho^{-1}\rangle$. From here, it's easy to see that $D_n\approx\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$ if and only if $\varphi(n)=2$, meaning $n$ must be either $3$, $4$, or $6$.

---

Did I cover all my bases here? At the very least I know that $D_5\not\approx\operatorname{Aut}(D_5)$, and the same goes for $D_8$. I feel confident about my proof, save for the fact that $\rho\sigma=\sigma\rho^{-1}$ needs proving. But, sometimes there's some weird one-off case where maybe a certain property is only true for $n=1,2,3,$ and $7349$, so I wanted to double check that I'm not messing anything up. Thank you!

Comment: It is indeed false for $n=2$, because of $$\text{Aut}\left(D_2\right)\cong\text{Aut}\left(C_2\times C_2\right)\cong \text{GL}_2\left(\mathbb{F}_2\right)\cong S_3$$ And because of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836900/prove-that-operatornameautd-n-le-n-phin) we know that  $2n= n\phi (n)$, i.e., $2=\phi(n)$ as you said.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205086/mathrmautd-4-is-isomorphic-to-d-4) for the proof of ${\rm Aut}(D_4)\cong D_4$. Clearly also ${\rm Aut}(D_3)\cong D_3$ and ${\rm Aut}(D_6)\cong D_6$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773139/is-operatornameautd-12-simeq-d-12?noredirect=1&lq=1).